# Variable assigned inside a loop works, outside it does not. Why?

Tags: c, variables

I have just started trying to learn C programming, and I really want to understand how it works.

I want to write a program that counts the number of times I pressed ENTER, SPACE, and TAB. The following code works:

```
    while( (text = getchar()) != EOF){

    if(text == '\n')
        ++newlines;

    if(text == ' ')
        ++blanks;

    if(text == '\t')
        ++tabs;
}
```

However, the following code does not work:

```
text = getchar();

while( text != EOF){

    if(text == '\n')
        ++newlines;

    if(text == ' ')
        ++blanks;

    if(text == '\t')
        ++tabs;
}
```

I would like to know why it works when I assign the variable inside the loop, but not outside it.

If I assign it outside the loop and run the program in a console, the program simply stops after I hit ENTER.

Comment: in second one text never changes or is re-read so you get an infinite loop.  PS - NEVER call a `char` variable "text".  "text" sounds like a string variable or similar.

Comment: You don't declare ANY variables ANYWHERE in the above code. All you do is assign values to variables. The difference between the first and second example is that `getchar` is inside the loop in the first example. In the second it's outside. What will happen in the second example if you only read one character and then loop over that character again and again? It will never be EOF and hence will run forever.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Sani! I have edited it.

Comment: @ebyrob, thanks, I did not think about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case you are getting a new character every time the loop is run. A `while` loop will recheck the condition every time it reaches the end of the loop. In the second case, you are still checking every time, but the value is not changing--it is just the same value you started with. So if the first character is not EOF... well... you are infinitely looping!

You could fix the second case by reupdating `text` before iterating again:

```
text = getchar();

while( text != EOF){

    if(text == '\n')
        ++newlines;

    if(text == ' ')
        ++blanks;

    if(text == '\t')
        ++tabs;

    text = getchar(); //added
}
```

Comment: I was trying to come up with a good explanation incorporating conditional "side effects" as well as the iteration without increment which you explain here.  But... it's pretty complicated.  What's going to happen when `while(x || (y=1) == x)` comes up and how do we convey that good style would often minimize "coding in the side effects".  (ie: don't learn bad habits from copying questionable code)

Comment: I think it just comes down to explaining that there is a place for everything in programming. Conditionals inside of while loops are not a place for assignment, and there is always a more readable and safer way to achieve the same result. Never attempt to "code golf" a solution to a problem because it uses less text

Comment: I must admit a certain addiction to T operators which I won't fully name here for fear of corrupting someone.  I may think my use is OK but there probably is no acceptable use for them.  Much like skipping curly braces in a loop or branch only worse.  PS - You must not like AJAX very much.